# Autodesk Forge Data Viz components work with an SVF model but not an SVF2 model

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

Our team participated in the forbidden city forge accelerator and the forge developer team helped us create our own version of a digital twin. We had a large model so we decided to test the SVF2 model derivative. The model did load in the viewer but the data viz sprites did not appear.
When we tried the SVF version everything worked as expected.
So we are unable to determine what the problem is or how to resolve it and any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Update 2021-05-14:**

SVF2 is supported now, please refer to:

- https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/dataviz/v1/developers_guide/quickstart/replace_model/
- https://github.com/yiskang/forge-dataviz-iot-reference-app/commit/efdee567819d8e98bd0351aa4ac6590d79768075

During Forbidden City forge accelerator, we found the SVF2 is unsupported and reported it as `HYPER-260` to let our engineering team allocate time to evaluate the possibility and explore the root cause. This means that the DataViz extension doesn't SVF2 currently, so please stay tuned with us. We appreciate your understanding and patience.

Comment: @jash SVF2 is supported now, so I updated my answer above.

Comment: Awesome, Thank you for letting me know!